# How can I fix the overwritePermissions error?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a mute command.I am using v12 version. While coding this command I got stuck in the Permissions part.
can you help me please
Commands ;

```
if (!muterole) {
            try {
                muterole = await message.guild.roles.create({ data: {
                    name: 'Muted',
                    color: '#000000',
                    permission: [] 
                }});
                message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
                    await channel.overwritePermissions(muterole, {
                        'SEND_MESSAGES': false,
                        'ADD_REACTION': false,
                        'CONNECT': false
                    });
                });
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        };
    
        if (user.roles.cache.has(muterole)) return message.channel.send(`**${user.user.username}** Başarıyla tamamlandı.`)
        user.roles.add(muterole)
        message.channel.send(`**${user.user.username}, Başarıyla mutelendi!**`);
```

Error:
`<node:4788> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied overwrites is not an Array or Collection of Permission Overwrites.`

Answer (score 0):

[`overwritePermissions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions) requires an array in the permission field like this.

```
channel.overwritePermissions([
  {
     id: muterole.id,
     deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'the rest of your permissions'],
  },
], 'Needed to change permissions');
```

The way you have it here is used in [`updateOverwrite`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=updateOverwrite), which is the better option anyway because it doesn't remove all permissions you had on channels before.

So to fix this, simply replace `overwritePermissions` with `updateOverwrite`.